# Restore database from a shared folder

Tags: sql-server, backup, restore

I did a backup of a database on Prod. I need to restore it to cert. 
I am Running below query on Cert to access the backup residing on prod

Query:

```
USE [master]
RESTORE DATABASE DB
FROM  DISK = N'\\SQL2005Prod\Backups\DB\DB.bak' WITH  FILE = 1,  
GO
```

Error:

> Msg 3201, Level 16, State 2, Line 3
>   Cannot open backup device '\\SQL2005Prod\Backups\DB\DB.bak'. Operating system error 5(Access is denied.).
>   Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Additional notes:
I am a sys admin on the server.
SQL Server Agent and I have full access to the folder Backups. 
SQL Server Agent account and SQL server Service account are under the same domain name. They have full control under folder permissions.

Comment: Is there any problem using the Sql Server management studio Restore wizard???. BTW your problem is with your path. Try some physical path like C:\, D:\ if you have permissions

Comment: Through GUI resotre wizard I cant see the shared drive(folder) backups.

Comment: You cannot retore backups from Shared Locations over network. You need to copy it on you local drive.

Comment: @Amit that is not true ***at all***.

Comment: @AaronBertrand  This is what is my personal exp, whenever I tried to restore back up from Shared Location , i did got the same permission error.

Comment: @Amit your comment makes it sound like a permission error is the end of the world, and that's all there is to it. Permission errors can be resolved (you know, by granting the right permissions to the right accounts).

Comment: You talk about SQL Server Agent and you. What about the SQL Server service account? What account is it using? If it's a local account, how exactly have you granted it permissions to the remote share? (Hint: a local account is not considered to be inside of "Everyone" in the domain or on the remote machine.)

Comment: There is a disconnect in the Query SQL above and the Error message below it. The SQL references \\SQL2005Prod\ but the Error message references \\SQL2005\ as the server names.

Comment: I changed few names when I was posting the question. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Have you tried going the other way--do a backup from Cert to the prod?  Otherwise try logging in with the same account the sql server is using and try doing any file operations with the share.

Comment: Is the SQL service account a domain account?  I don't see that noted here.

Comment: I believe database restores and backups are executed using the database engine's service account. As mentioned in the previous comments you should verify that that account has both access through the folder Share permissions as well as the NTFS folder permissions.

Comment: @ Daryl that worked. I did a backup of prod onto cert and was able to restore it onto cert. But I still wonder why I am not able to restore it from prod backup. Until then thanks everyone for their time, it did resolve my issue :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server accesses external resources under:

- *impersonation*, if the original login is an NT login
- *service account*, if the original login is a SQL login w/o a mapped credential
- *credential*, if the original login is a SQL login that has a [mapped credential](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189522.aspx)

So the user which actually accesses the share will depend on how you logged in to SQL at the moment you issued the RESTORE statement. Note also that if NT login is used then normal constrained delegation rules for impersonation are in place (aka. 'kerberos double hop', if your original login occured on a different [LSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_Security_Authority_Subsystem_Service) than the one hosting the SQL Server service and the target resource resides on a host different from the SQL Server service host then you'll be authenticated by the target resource's LSA as 'anonymous' unless you explicitly configure delegation *for that resource*).

PS. SQL Agent adds 'proxies' to the mixture, but those are nothing else but credentials (case 3 in my list). See [Create a SQL Server Agent Proxy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175834.aspx).