# How do I make a SQL Server Job connect to another server to run a Query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sqlcmd, sql-agent-job

I'm attempting to create a SQL Server Job that shuts off high availability, changes a database to the simple recovery model, run a backup to clear the transaction log, do a database shrink, set a database to full recovery model, run a full backup, then turn high availability back on. I already have all of this scripted out, however I don't have a way to run the needed scripts on the secondary server through the job.

To further clarify if that's not enough:
Primary Server has a Database.
Secondary Server needs the Database from the Primary Server backed up on it for High Availability.
This requires me to run scripts on both the Primary Server and the Secondary Server.
In order to do this, I need to be able to connect to the secondary server and run a script in a SQL Server Agent Job on the primary server.

How would I go about doing this? What do I need to write in order for SQL Server's T-SQL (Or any other SQL Server Job-step Type).

I've tried :Connect but that won't work unless I load it into sqlcmd, and it always gets stuck when I try to run sqlcmd through a SQL Agent Job. I've also tried making it connect to the server through sqlcmd (sqlcmd -S (server_name)) and running a script on the server locally, but that hasn't worked either.

Comment: For the remote server, use a CmdExec job step that executes SQLCMD to run your script. Specify the remote server name via the `-S` argument.

Comment: Create a linked server, then do `EXEC LinkedServer.master.sys.sp_executesql N'your query here'` or `EXEC LinkedServer.msdb..sp_start_job` etc

Comment: @DanGuzman That's what I used to run it through sqlcmd, the problem is it never exits out of that step and runs indefinitely.

Comment: @LYNITS, does the step run indefinitely because the query run by SQLCMD runs indefinitely?

Comment: @DanGuzman No, if I run the query manually through sqlcmd, it completes without issue.

Comment: @Charlieface When I attempt to run it with the first option, it tells me it cannot find the specified backup file (The backup file is on another server that I reference with '\\\(other server)\filepath\file.bak'). Am I unable to reference a file on another server in this way?

Comment: Not unless the SQL Server service user account has permission on that server, which is unlikely. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18749224/restore-database-from-a-shared-folder and https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/199237/sql-server-service-permissions-on-network-share-depending-on-integratedsecurity All in all it's probably a bad idea to backup/restore directly from a network share, just backup to a local location and copy it over another way.

Comment: @Charlieface Just to confirm, am I able to run a Restore using EXEC LinkedServer.master.sys.sp_executesql N'your query here'? That is what I'm attempting to do and it's throwing a syntax error.

Comment: That should work as long as that linked server has access to the backup location, what syntax error are you getting? Are you parameterizing everything properly? What's your code?

Comment: @Charlieface EXEC server2.master.sys.sp_executesql N'RESTORE DATABASE [Database] FROM DISK = N"\\server3\filepath\backupfile.bak" WITH NORECOVERY,  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 5' I've also tried replacing the double-quotes with single quotes around the file path. The error is saying "Incorrect Syntax near keyword 'with'". And also Incorrect syntax near 'N'.

Comment: Not double quotes or single quotes, but doubled-up (x2) single quotes `''` for example `EXEC server2.master.sys.sp_executesql N'RESTORE DATABASE [Database] FROM DISK = N''\\server3\filepath\backupfile.bak'' WITH NORECOVERY, NOUNLOAD, STATS = 5'` You should ideally parameterize this eg `DECLARE @db sysname = 'Database', @filename nvarchar(256) = 'pathHere'; EXEC server2.master.sys.sp_executesql N'RESTORE DATABASE @db FROM DISK = @filename WITH NORECOVERY, NOUNLOAD, STATS = 5', @db = @db, @filename = @filename;`

Comment: @Charlieface This fixes the syntax error, however it is attempting to run this on server1 not server 2. I know this for a fact because it is stating the database is in use (When the database doesn't exist on the server2). This tells me it's trying to restore the database on server1.

Comment: Are you sure you did `EXEC server2.master.sys.sp_executesql` and not `EXEC master.sys.sp_executesql` and are you sure SSMS is connected to the correct server? And have you double-checked the database does not exist `select * from server2.master.sys.databases`

Comment: @Charlieface I can confirm I used EXEC server2.master.sys.sp_executesql. SSMS is running this through server1. I ran the select statement you gave me on server1 (As it would be doing if I was running this as a job on server1) and it showed me all of the databases on server1. The "server2" part of the statement doesn't seem to be doing anything, and it seems to just be running everything on server1.

Comment: I think you have something messed up with your Linked Server settings. Maybe `server2` is actually configured to loopback to the same server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a linked server then ran the following:

```
EXEC server2.master.sys.sp_executesql N'RESTORE DATABASE [Database1] FROM  DISK = N''\\fileshare\folder\Database1.bak'' WITH  NORECOVERY,  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 5'
```

This is the syntax I am using for all of the steps.